# How do I call the retrieveStudents() from my cron job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Java development and Spring/Springboot. I was tasked to create a cron job that would execute a query to a database. Although, my problem would focus on calling the function since it's already existing in the project. I'm still quite confused and learning about Dependency Injection, Design Patterns and Spring. I tried to resolve this myself, but it's taking a while now -- so I figured to ask while I'm also trying to figure it out just to save time in case they ask me for a deadline. Thank you so much in advance!

This is how the programs are generally structured:

**QueryConfig.java**

 This is a new and only file I created. I was able to make the cron job work, as I tried to put a logger inside runQuery() and it was able to run every 5 minutes as per the configuration file.

```
@RefreshScope
@Component
public class QueryConfig {

    @Value("${cron.job.query}")
    private String sql;

    String name = "Bob";

    StudentMgtApiDelegate delegate = new StudentMgtApiDelegateImpl();

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.job.schedule}", zone = "${cron.job.timezone}")
    public void runQuery() {
        delegate.retrieveStudents(name);
    }

}
```

**StudentMgtApiDelegateImpl.java**

 Please also note that this is just a representation of the code since I cannot share the actual. I'll try my best to make it as close to the real implementation. There are 3 methods for the API, but I just want to call the retrieveStudents().

```
@Component
public class StudentMgtApiDelegateImpl implements StudentMgtApiDelegate {

    @Autowired
    private StudentFacade studentFacade;   

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> retrieveStudents(String name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentFacade.retrieveStudents(
           ...
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDetails> retrieveStudentDetails(String name...) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentFacade.retrieveStudentDetails(
           ...
        ));
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<CountBreakdown>> retrieveStudentCounts(String name) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(studentFacade.studentCountsRetrieve(
           ...
        ));
    }  
    
}
```

**StudentFacade.java**

```
public class StudentFacade {
    private Function<DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>>, List<Student>> studentListRetrieveFn;
    private Function<DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>>, StudentDetails> studentDetailsRetrieveFn;
    private Function<DataWrapper<StudentRetrieveCriteria>, List<CountBreakdown>> studentCountsRetrieveFn;

    public StudentFacade(Function<DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>>, List<Student>> studentListRetrieveFn, Function<DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>>, StudentDetails> studentDetailsRetrieveFn, Function<DataWrapper<StudentRetrieveCriteria>, List<CountBreakdown>> studentCountsRetrieveFn) {
        this.studentListRetrieveFn = studentListRetrieveFn;
        this.studentDetailsRetrieveFn = studentDetailsRetrieveFn;
        this.studentCountsRetrieveFn = studentCountsRetrieveFn;
    }

    public List<Student> retrieveStudents(DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>> wrapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(wrapper).map(studentListRetrieveFn).orElse(null);
    }

    public StudentDetails retrieveStudentDetails(DataWrapper<StudentParams<String>> wrapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(wrapper).map(studentDetailsRetrieveFn).orElse(null);
    }

    public List<CountBreakdown> studentCountsRetrieve(DataWrapper<StudentRetrieveCriteria> wrapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(wrapper).map(studentCountsRetrieveFn).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

I apologize in advance for the many code omissions and I know some parameters won't match and make sense. But as of the current implementation in my QueryConfig.java, I am encountering this error:

```
[scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I tried to debug and see the value of **delegate** inside the QueryConfig.java, and it has a studentFacade that is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowire the `StudentMgtApiDelegate`; do not construct it manually.

```java
@Autowired
StudentMgtApiDelegate delegate;
```